# The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Tags: oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

Suddenly i can't run

`add-migration a -ProjectName MyProject.Model -ConnectionString "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=1.1.1.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=mydb)));Persist Security Info=True;User Id=myuser;Password=xxxx;" -ConnectionProviderName "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"`

anymore, It gives me

```
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

I tried reinstalling Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client for the project but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it was but at some point I saw EntityFramework related errors so I updated EntityFramework to the latest 6.2.0 for all project and the error is gone now